# Checking record size in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to check the size of a record in Ocaml? Something like `sizeof` of C/C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
# Obj.size (Obj.repr (1,2,3,4,5)) ;;
- : int = 5
```

But for a record type, the size only depends on the type declaration, so you could just infer it from that.

The actual size occupied in memory is the number returned by `Obj.size` plus one in words. Words are 32 or 64 bit depending which OCaml version you are using. The additional word is used for book-keeping.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Obj module, there is also a Objsize library from Dmitry Grebeniuk ( http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/objsize/ ). It allows you to get more detailed info about values and its size.